# Spacing issue with Form in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a view where the top bit is an input field, when the user presses the search button, the results will display below. This works, but the results are appearing half way down the screen, rather than directly under the query field.

I have mocked it up below with some results showing the issue. I am sure it is a quick fix, but I just cannot see what it is.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Lookup: View {
@State var query = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        Form {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Text Field", text: $query)
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            print("Button Hit")
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle")
                        })
                }
            }.padding()
        }
        
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(1..<11) { resultNumber in
                ResultRow(resultNumber: resultNumber)
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct ResultRow: View {
var resultNumber:Int

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Result \(resultNumber)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(alignment: .leading)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("This is the result text")
                        .font(.caption)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Text("Some more details")
                    .font(.caption)
                Text("and some more details")
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }.padding()
}
}

struct WaterwaysLookup2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    Lookup()
}
}
```

[image: The result as it is]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form` takes all available space, just like `ScrollView`, so they each take half! You should limit `Form` like in code:

```
struct Lookup: View {
    @State var query = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Form {

                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Text Field", text: $query)
                        Button(
                            
                            action: {
                                print("Button Hit")
                                
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle")
                            })
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
            .frame(height: 120)  // <<: Here!
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(1..<11) { resultNumber in
                    ResultRow(resultNumber: resultNumber)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]